# Is it possible to create a DocuSign developer account via REST calls?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to automate the creation of a saleforce org environment for testing, i'm able to install the docusign app but I would like to also create a developer sandbox account in the same go without having to go to the UI to do it. Is that possible? I captured the requests but I'm not able to actually go through the whole flow because I eventually end up erroring with `CSRF verification failed.` errors.

Has anyone tried this before or know if it's even possible?

Answer (score 1):

The functionality to create Sandbox accounts is not exposed as an API that's generally accessible. I'd recommend emailing go-live@docusign.com with your account information to get the discussion rolling on enabling this functionality for you.