# Automating the process of creating and configuring a new DocuSign developer account via API

Tags: docusignapi

Right now I'm exploring potential options for automating the process of creating and configuring new DocuSign developer accounts via API calls, as this would allow my team to greatly reduce the work needed to setup and configure these accounts manually. I can't find any information in the current DocuSign API documentation that would allow for this, and the only question I could find online was [Is it possible to create a DocuSign developer account via REST calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56279332/is-it-possible-to-create-a-docusign-developer-account-via-rest-calls) from 2019.

Is it possible to create new developer accounts via an API? The POST requests utilized by the UI don't look to be designed in a way that would easily allow for this.

Comment: Can you explain why you would need to create accounts? I wonder if you may mean users and not accounts. You can have many people using your account, and maybe that's what you mean?

Comment: @InbarGazit our current process is to create separate developer accounts because each account is tied to a different customer/implementation project and we need to maintain the separation in terms of who has access to the data being used.

Answer (score 0):

There's an endpoint in the eSignature API called [Accounts:Create](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/accounts/accounts/create/) that enables creating new accounts.

However, it's important to note this:

**This method is restricted to partner integrations. You must work with DocuSign Professional Services or DocuSign Business Development, who will provide you with the Distributor Code and Distributor Password that you need to include in the request body.**